# Remote API call with bearer Token and net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error

Tags: angular, api

I am trying to access data from a remote REST API with Bearer Token and getting the error below:
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I have resolved the CORS issue and followed the steps in Google browser to fix the error, still I am not able to get the data.

Please assist me.

Below is the portion of my code:

```
let header_object = {

  'Accept'       : 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
  'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token,

};

  const httpOptions = {headers: header_object };
  console.log(httpOptions);
  return this.http.get<JSON>(this.baseurl, httpOptions);
```

Comment: Is it causing the same issue in all browsers or in chrome only? How do you know that you have fixed CORS issue? What error were you getting before fixing it and what after fixing it?

Comment: @SumitParakh Google and Opera show the same, IE does not show anything but I am not having the data. Before that I was getting 'no header present for Access-Control-Allow-Origin' but now it is gone.Thanks

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be present in server side code, not front end code. Make sure that the API allows call from external sources.

Comment: @SumitParakh will Postman request work in that case?

Comment: It should not if you are calling API from different domain from postman and the API doesn't allow that...   for example, if API is located at xyz.com and you are testing that from post man. it should work...   But you are calling xyz.com from abc.com through postman, it should not work, unless xyz.com allows cross-origin requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, postman will allow any public apis even if Allow-Access-Origin is set for some other domain.

Here is the example, try this url :

```
http://ankama.akamaized.net/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/200/178102.png
```

[image]

Many developers, confuse this as if it only allows mentioned origin. That is partially correct.

To answer that, [Cors](https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/#) was introduced to prevent a malicious script on one page from obtaining access to sensitive data on another web page, i.e whenever an origin changes thus "Cross-Origin" .

I answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112722/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-403-image/57127591#57127591)

Now, to allow which particular origin or all origins is decided only at the **server end**

Now, Lets assume all the configurations are correct from server end, but still you won't be able to access from your host until unless you use **proxy** answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56919538/how-to-fetch-data-using-http-post-request-in-angular-7/56919588#56919588)